# Promises with Mongoose methods

Tags: mongoose

I was wondering what the standard way of returning data from a Mongoose method was. From the examples I've seen online, it seems that a common way of doing this is by including a callback as an argument in the method.

So for example I might have a findFriends method on my User model

```
UserSchema.methods.findFriends = callback => {
  ...
  return callback(null, friends);
};
```

To then use this method in my application I have made things work by creating a promise. But my solution feels quite clunky and probably not a best practice. Should I be implementing promises within the method on the UserSchema? I've never seen it done like this which is why I was curious to know some other perspectives on this.

```
const user = User.findOne();

friendsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  user.findFriends((error, friends) => {
    if(! error) {
      resolve(friends);
    } else {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
});

friendsPromise.then(friends => {
  console.dir(friends);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't really care what your method returns. If you want to use promises instead of callbacks, just return a promise:

```
UserSchema.methods.findFriends = function() { // see text
  ...
  return promiseReturningFunction();
};
```

Some remarks:

- instead of using the arrow notation for methods, I would suggest using a function expression (`= function() { ... }`). Mongoose sets the value of `this` to the document instance, which would get lost if you use arrow notation;
- Most built-in Mongoose methods return promises themselves, so `promiseReturningFunction` could be the result of, say, `User.find({ friend : ... }).exec()`. See [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) for more info.